# Influence of author on other authors

Tags: citations, google-scholar, bibliometrics

How can I find out which authors are influenced how strongly by a certain academic author X?

Comment: @Dmitry and his supporters: then why does this site have the tags "google-scholar", "citations", "bibliometrics", and so on? You mods are being "supportive" as usual.

Comment: Some questions on Google Scholar, citations and bibliometrics are specific to academia. Unfortunately, in my opinion, your question is mostly technical and concerned with a particular software (see [boat programming](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14470/what-is-the-boat-programming-meme-about)). Perhaps, it can be on topic on Stack Overflow?

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov I don't agree that the nature of this question is technical. The question is about where a specific type of data can be obtained, and this data is academia-specific.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper The data are academia-specific, but the process of obtaining them (which is the topic of the question) is not. Similarly, if the OP were to analyse data on cats, the right place to ask their question would not be cats.SE, but Stack Overflow or CrossValidated.SE.

Comment: @DmitrySavostyanov We may agree that the question is a bit vague and permits both technical and non-technical answers. It could be answered with some complex technical instructions to scrape Google Scholar for the relevant data. But my answer is not technical at all: it specifies a website where one can put the name of an author into a search field, and obtains a list of the researchers they cite most often and were most often cited by.

Comment: This question has just been re-opened. I suggest that you try to clarify more exactly what you mean - if you want to know how to find out how many times X is cited by Y, for example, then ask that.

Comment: @Flyto Why am I not allowed to ask one question about *any* influence metric, and another question about the exact number of citations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A website that offers some related information: http://www.semanticscholar.org. Sadly, they don't give the precise number of citations, but a list of "influencing" and "influenced" researchers based on a metric which incorporates the number of citations.

Comment: Thanks! I found only "authors most influenced by X" under "view author influence", which does not seem to perfectly correlate with the number of citations, but rather seems to be some weighted AI-based metric. Is that the only metric you're aware of?

Comment: @root Whoops, then I didn't remember that correctly, sorry for that. The metric combines number of citations with something they call the number of "very influential citations", that is, citations that appear in particular statements such as "we use/extend the work by X".